# CSS issues with OSx Sierra

Tags: html, css, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I have an application where we have few absolutely positioned divs.
The issue is, some customers using OSX Sierra are unable to see certain parts of the app and it seems that those parts are hidden behind the absolutely positioned DIVs. The Wierd part is that as soon as developer console is opened, everything works fine. But the moment, developer console is closed, it again starts acting crazy so there's no better way to debug this feature.

I tested this on 5 different client's machine remotely on Chrome, Safari & Firefox and the same issue occurs.

Not sure how can an OS affect a web application.
The only common thing I've noticed is that all the customers complaining about this issue are using OSx Sierra.

Is there a known issue?

Comment: Paste the code of the div. Please.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it is not about the clients software.
Try to add `position:relative;width:100%;` to a div around your absolute divs. Then the maximum width of your absolute divs should be the clients browser width, unless your width is set in pixels.